# How to scrape one chrome extension popup with my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension to gather all my feeds from webpages and extensions into one popup. I can scrape webpages fairly easy using `html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;` and regexp.

I want to scrape the html of a chrome extension (preferably using xpath) I have installed that I did not write, ie I installed it from the extension store. I've tried to google this but I don't see anything suitable. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Open the extension's popup page in a normal tab and use [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) to inspect it.

Comment: @wOxxOm which will require enabling chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls

Comment: Well, I guess. Or `--whitelisted-extension-id`. Anyway, the task is quite complicated.

Comment: I'm struggling. I can't find any examples. I'll update if I get anything working.